# Swiperjs changed CDN url, how can I prevent bugs in future?

Tags: url, http-status-code-404, cdn, swiper.js, unpkg

I'm using Swiperjs in my website. Today I saw that swiper is not working, and in console were 404 errors, because css and js files could not be found.

I am using swiper from CDN, in the way that is written on swiperjs website https://swiperjs.com/get-started/

Now the problem: when I developed my website, there was a different url to swiper CDN (writen in swiperjs website, last year).
In my code, before, was this, and it worked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

Today, this code gave me errors. So I changed to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And this now works.

My question is:

how can I be sure that in future there won't be any changes like this?  Am I more safe if I download these scripts and include them in project?

I thought that CDN should always work.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your information. finally my gallery start to showing images. Realy appreciate about your search in change of swiper css resources. I think we should donate/bought the copy of swiper css and install to our website server, CMIIW.